# Missing system Settings in 14.04 LTS

Tags: apt, sound, dpkg, dbus

I just installed 14.04 and tried talking on Skype but the other party can't hear me. I tried checking the sound settings from System settings  and  found out that System settings is missing. I ran the command `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` and got the error message

```
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I later ran the command  `sudo apt-get install unity-control-center` and still got the message

```
Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Meanwhile, I always get an error message popping up each time I switch on my laptop:

```
System Program Problem detected
Do you want to report problem?
```

I have also uninstalled and re-installed System Settings(Unity Control Center) via Ubuntu Software Center and it still doesn't work.

Any urgent help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Did you check your .ISO file's integrity before installing? Sounds like either a bug or you used a corrupted file.

Comment: See this link https://translate.google.co.in/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fdebianforum.de%2Fforum%2Fviewtopic.php%3Ft%3D142652%26p%3D935121&edit-text=

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I solve this error related to gnome-terminal & software updater?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083561/how-can-i-solve-this-error-related-to-gnome-terminal-software-updater)